# visual studio docker template container running throgh command line but not being found when searched in the browser

Tags: visual-studio, docker, .net-core, docker-compose, containers

I created solution with VS for an .net core API, and enabled Docker Support for Linux containers, also enabled OpenAPI support. I even have other version with docker-compose support.

Both versions, Im able to run the containers in the Visual studio and the browser immediately pops with everything ok.

The problem is I need to zip and send it and people must be able to run it without VS, just by running a container throgh the command line...

This are the files generated without docker-compose:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["PhoneNumberAggregator/PhoneNumberAggregator.csproj", "PhoneNumberAggregator/"]
RUN dotnet restore "PhoneNumberAggregator/PhoneNumberAggregator.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/PhoneNumberAggregator"
RUN dotnet build "PhoneNumberAggregator.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "PhoneNumberAggregator.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PhoneNumberAggregator.dll"]
```

launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:60906",
      "sslPort": 44316
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "PhoneNumberAggregator": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/swagger",
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "useSSL": true
    }
  }
}
```

And this are the files generated with docker-compose (counting with the above):

this are available in VS:

docker-compose.yml(in this file I added ports: -8080:443 to when it launches in VS goes in localhost:8080):

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  phonenumberaggregator:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}phonenumberaggregator
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: PhoneNumberAggregator/Dockerfile
    ports:
    - "8080:443"
```

and .dockerignore:

```
**/.classpath
**/.dockerignore
**/.env
**/.git
**/.gitignore
**/.project
**/.settings
**/.toolstarget
**/.vs
**/.vscode
**/*.*proj.user
**/*.dbmdl
**/*.jfm
**/azds.yaml
**/bin
**/charts
**/docker-compose*
**/Dockerfile*
**/node_modules
**/npm-debug.log
**/obj
**/secrets.dev.yaml
**/values.dev.yaml
LICENSE
README.md
```

still in the docker-composer version but not available in VS I have the following files:

in solution folder:

docker-compose.dcproj:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" Sdk="Microsoft.Docker.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectVersion>2.1</ProjectVersion>
    <DockerTargetOS>Linux</DockerTargetOS>
    <ProjectGuid>39323510-da14-4594-918a-c8300beaa110</ProjectGuid>
    <DockerLaunchAction>LaunchBrowser</DockerLaunchAction>
    <DockerServiceUrl>{Scheme}://localhost:{ServicePort}/swagger</DockerServiceUrl>
    <DockerServiceName>phonenumberaggregator</DockerServiceName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="docker-compose.override.yml">
      <DependentUpon>docker-compose.yml</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="docker-compose.yml" />
    <None Include=".dockerignore" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

and docker-compose.override.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  phonenumberaggregator:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    volumes:
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
```

and in both versions I have inside the project this file:

PhoneNumberAggregator.csproj.user:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="Current" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ActiveDebugProfile>Docker</ActiveDebugProfile>
    <Controller_SelectedScaffolderID> ApiControllerWithActionsScaffolder</Controller_SelectedScaffolderID>
    <Controller_SelectedScaffolderCategoryPath> root/Common/Api</Controller_SelectedScaffolderCategoryPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

By the way in VS when its running I see this Ports

For Docker version:

[image]

For docker-compose version:

[image]

Comment: 1. What URL are you using? 2. What is the message you see in the browser?

Comment: The message is: not possible to access the website and the url Ive tried everything since: localhost:443, localhost:80, localhost:8080, localhost:5000, localhost:5001...

Comment: What URL does visual studio use? You should at least know what port to expect. I don't see port 5000 or 5001 anywhere in any of those config files. It looks like you are mapping port 8080 to port 443, so I guess you should focus on 8080. 443 is https so you should try `https://localhost:8080` or `https://127.0.0.1:8080`. "not possible to access the website" is not a message that I've ever seen in a browser.

Comment: I added images to the end of my question showing what ports VS uses.. 5000 and 5001 is in launchsettings.json and I didnt know if it would override or something.. about the message, I translated from my language to english, the error is this: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED..

Comment: OMG @Nick.McDermaid Im going to cry here! I used https and it worked.. spent all night doing this and never thought typing https would make a difference.. Make it an answear and I will upvote it. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like port 8080 is mapped to port 443

port 433 is https so make sure you should are using https://localhost:8080 or https://127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: Thank you mate, that was the problem I'm glad you reached me on this because I never saw it being https the problem